# Raid 0 not recognised by File Manager

Tags: windows-10, raid

I had a 2x2TB Raid 0 setup and healthy. I fitted a new 6TB HDD, in doing I unplugged my 2x2TB raid drives to reorganise the drives in the case.

Now Windows File Manager says I need to format the Raid 0 drive which I don't want to do. Intel Optane says the Raid is healthy. Disc Manager said the drive was unassigned.

I've changed the drive letter back to what it was originally, tried setting the Raid to Dynamic and set it to a Simple Volume but Windows File manager still doesn't see it. I tried unplugging the drives and swapping sata plugs but no joy. I've tried the free versions of recovery programs and the can 'see' the files fine. I was hoping to find a fix that didn't involve buying a program that I'll probably only use once and may not even work.

Running Windows 10 Pro. The OS is on a SSD and is not affected.

Any useful suggestions would be well recieved!
[image: hard drive setup]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the RAID0 is badly assembled (disk swapped or something like this...). In such a case, you should avoid modifying anything in the logical volume. Setting it to Dynamic could write on it at a random area.

What I would do is to revert strictly to the original situation (removing the 6TB...). And see if you get back your device. (If so, backup).

But state-of-art RAID arrays use metadata in each disk to be sure they are assembled correctly. Here, I am quite puzzled.

Recovery programs may not be able to access each drive individualy, which would make a recovery difficult. I would only pay for a program which is claimed to handle Intel Octane configurations.

Comment: thanks. I had already tried reverting to the original configuration to no avail. I'm thinking I'll have to buy Stellar Data Recovery of something similar. After your suggestion I'll be looking carefully at their capabilities.

Comment: I have already made a recovery program to get back some file after a Tchernobyl virus. It was easy since the disk was defragmented and all files on adjacent sector. If the RAID0 is assembled swapped, this hypothesis won't apply. If on the other hand you just have lost the first sectors with the partition table, a recovery program will proceed easily.